# newpage within figure environment

Tags: floats, minipage

How do I make a newpage within the figure environment. I want to make, lets say 16 small figures using the minipage, but the size of the figures can't fit on one page, so I want it to split in two. Is there any way to do it within the same figure environment or do I really need to make it manual, ending the figure, \newpage , beginning new figure.

Comment: Float environments generally can't break across pages. I would personally suggest that you insert the images without the figure environment and use the command `\captionof` from the `capt-of` package to set the caption.

Comment: Why are you talking about captions, is there something i dont know ?. I mean my intention has nothing to do with caption does it??

Comment: I choosed to fix it the "hard way" by making two figure enviroments including the minipages and then seperating them by an \newpage

Comment: As my suggestion involves including images without using the `figure` environment, you can not use the usual `\caption` command, that will only work inside floating environments. I have therefore included information on how to add captions to images outside of a `figure` environment.

Comment: see if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages/278748#278748 is close to what you looking for. it looks that your question is duplicate to it.

Answer (score 2):

The figure environment is a floating object that is moved to a page and  position where it fits best according to several rules, that can be several pages after it is coded. Therefore a `\newpage` inside a float have no sense.

But you can use images and captions without a float, as pointed in the  leandriis's comment, ... or you can make **two page floats** and ensure that the first one appear in a even page using the `dpfloat` package, that allow you to format a double-page figure.

You do not specify if should be one or two cations, or captions for every subfigure. This is a simple MWE with two captions:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{dpfloat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{leftfullpage}
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}\medskip\par
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-c}\medskip\par
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}\medskip\par
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{the left-side figures}
\end{leftfullpage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{fullpage}
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-c}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}\medskip\par
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image}\medskip\par
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-c}\medskip\par
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{fullpage}
\caption{the right-side figures}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see. My fail; i need captions for every figure .

Comment: @andersbg Then one option is load also the package `subfigure` and put each  image in a in  `\subfigure[your subcaption]{\includegraphics[...]{...}}`