# Subtable spanning over several pages

Tags: tables, subcaption

I have a table composed of 2 subtables. I would like to be able to break the table to display the subtables on different pages. It seems it is not working like subfigures and `\ContinuedFloat` [as it it presented here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages). It seems to me that the `\longtable` environment is not suited for that purpose either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{General caption. \label{tab:mytable}

\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\caption{Caption subtable 1}\label{cst1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|l|}
Name & Description\\
\hline
a & This is a \\ 
b & This is b \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{subtable}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\caption{Caption subtable 2}\label{cst2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|l|}
Name & Description\\
\hline
c & This is c \\ 
d & This is d \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{subtable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the exact same way as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/278748/36296 you can use `\ContinuedFloat` to split the subtables in two separate floats:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

test

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{General caption.} \label{tab:mytable}

\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\caption{Caption subtable 1}\label{cst1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|l|}
Name & Description\\
\hline
a & This is a \\ 
b & This is b \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\pagebreak

\begin{table}[htbp]
\ContinuedFloat
\caption{General caption, continued.}% remove if the second subtible shall not have a general caption
\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\caption{Caption subtable 2}\label{cst2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|l|}
Name & Description\\
\hline
c & This is c \\ 
d & This is d \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{subtable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

Off-topic, but I suggest to not use vertical lines in your tables and use the `booktabs` package instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

test

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{General caption.} \label{tab:mytable}

\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\caption{Caption subtable 1}\label{cst1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
Name & Description\\
\midrule
a & This is a \\ 
b & This is b \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\pagebreak

\begin{table}[htbp]
\ContinuedFloat
\caption{General caption, continued.}% remove if the second subtible shall not have a general caption
\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\caption{Caption subtable 2}\label{cst2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
Name & Description\\
\midrule
c & This is c \\ 
d & This is d \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{subtable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You may want to mention the possibility of providing the instruction `\caption{General caption, continued.}` immediately after `\ContinuedFloat`. Also, `\clearpage` may be a better way to go than `\pagebreak`, as the latter doesn't guarantee that pending floats will be flushed.