# Inserting full page subfigures

Tags: graphics, floats

I have tried to look through TeX.SE questions (e.g., like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages)) to figure out how to layout **full-page** subfigures (**two full-page figures that share the same caption**, but with their own subcaptions such as '(a)' and '(b)' as seen in the attached image below). I have tried to draw up that layout in Word as seen in the attached image. It'd be also nice to be able to put bounding boxes around each figure as well.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\captionof{subfigure}` pretty much anywhere.  There are lots of packages which will put boxes around figures or subfigures, but you really don't need it.  Just remember that the box also has to fit into the text area.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only
\begin{document}
{\centering
  \fbox{\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.8\textheight}}
  \captionof{subfigure}{title}
}\par
\end{document}
```

---

More to the specifics of your question:

Note that the figure caption will appear twice in the list of figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fbox{\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.8\textheight}}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{figure caption}
\end{figure}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
\begin{figure}[p]
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fbox{\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.8\textheight}}
    \setcounter{subfigure}{1}%
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. One quick question: where do I put the `\includegraphics` along with the location of the image in  the above example?

Comment: You can replace \rule with whatever your source image was.

Comment: thank you so much! One more question: if I would like to use custom subfigure caption (subcaption) instead of '(a)', '(b)', etc., what should I do? Thanks again!

Comment: \captionsetup[subfigure]{...} See the caption package manual for the available options.  The subcaption manual only shows the default setup (which interestlinly did not apply to \captionof{subfigure}).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know where the official documentation is, but found [this](http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/publishing/latex_captions#subfigure_and_subtable_captions_with_no_number_or_letter) and used `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}` to turn off the auto-captioning. :)

Comment: Every package comes with its own manual, although finding them can be difficult.  My caption manual is at "C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9\doc\latex\caption\caption-eng.pdf".  There are command line programs which can locate the manual giver the name, but I don't use them.  Instead I created a folder full of shortcuts (links).  That way I don't have to remember how to spell them.