# Discontinuation of subfigure captions

Tags: subfloats

I am using the following code to include four subfigures.

```
  \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{float}
    \begin {document}
        \begin{figure}[H]
          \centering
          \begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{2.5cm}}c}
          \begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{subfig_1.jpeg}
            \caption{subfig_1}
            \label{sub_1}
          \end{subfigure} &
          \begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{subfig_2.jpeg}
            \caption{subfig_2}
            \label{sub_2}
          \end{subfigure}
          \end{tabular}
          \caption{Figure:1}
        \end{figure}%
        \begin{figure}[H]\ContinuedFloat
          \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{subfig_3.jpeg}
            \caption{subfig_3}
            \label{sub_3}
          \end{subfigure}
          \vspace{1cm}\par
          \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{subfig_4.jpeg}
            \caption{subfig_4}
            \label{sub_4}
          \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Figure:1}
        \label{fig1}
        \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

I am using "\Continuedfloat" as the subfigures 3 and 4 are supposed to be inserted in the succeeding page of the page where subfigures 1 and 2 are inserted. The subcaptions for all the four subfigures are printed. However they are not continuous i.e. The subcaption for the subfigures 1 and 2 are numbered as "(a)" and "(b)" respectively. The subcaption for the subfigures 3 and 4 is supposed to be numbered as "(c)" and "(d)" respectively. But they are also labelled as "(a)" and ("b") respectively.  Also the subfigure 2 appears beyond the right margin of the page. And the subcaptions are not printed at the centre of the subfigures although I have used `\centering`. I am not able to figure out where I am making a mistake. Can someone please help me figure out?

I am also not sure whether the numbers ".4" and "1.2" that  I am using respectively in `\begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}` and `\includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]` i.e.

```
\begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{subfig_1.jpeg}
```

are correct. As in what is the allowed factor by which the number used in `\includegraphics` should be less or greater than the number used in `\begin{subfigure}`

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages?

Comment: If I make a minimal example using your code fragment, I can not reproduce the issues you describe.

Comment: @leandriis Then has it got to do with the dimensions of the figures I want to insert? They are quite large I would say. The dimensions of the subfigures 1,2,3 and 4 are respectively: "1521x1180" , "1372x1158" , "1826x1245" and "1833x1405." The unit of measure being pixels

Comment: If you compile your code, you should recieve an error message about `subcaption` and `subfig` being incompatible with each other. Remove the latter.

Comment: For the first two side by side subfigures, I'd also recomment to not use a `tabular`. Instead I'd use the following code:  `\centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subfig_1.jpeg}
    \caption{subfig1}
    \label{sub_1}
  \end{subfigure} \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subfig_2.jpeg}
    \caption{subfig2}
    \label{sub_2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Figure:1}` This will also solve the mentioned margin problem.

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you decide on the no ".45" used in the `\begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}`? Is that a sort of standard?

Comment: Try and error or personal preference. In my opinion, the white space between the two images is too large if one just ses 0.4.

Comment: See my answer on question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477813/. Your question is very related to this one.

Comment: Including the `subcaption` *and* the `subfig` package does not work. They are not compatible. And especially `subfig` has its own `\ContinuedFloat` code which breaks `\ContinuedFloat` offered by `subcaption`. So you have to decide for one of them and drop the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After repairing your code, made small modification and consider ma answer on [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477813/), I obtain the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin {document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subfig_1.jpeg}
        \caption{subfig\_1}
        \label{sub_1}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subfig_2.jpeg}
    \caption{subfig\_2}
    \label{sub_2}
\end{subfigure}
      \caption{Figure:1}
      \label{fig:fig-1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.8\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subfig_3.jpeg}
    \caption{subfig\_3}
    \label{sub_3}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.8\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subfig_4.jpeg}
    \caption{subfig\_4}
    \label{sub_4}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Figure:1 (cont.)}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```