# How to span subtables on different page

Tags: floats, subcaption

How to make subtables on different page.

I have 6 subtables, but some of them go beyond the margin. How to put 4 tables on the 1st page and the other 2 on the 2nd page? I know that we can use ``\continuedfloat'' to split subfigures. Is there any function to splite subtables?

```
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{title1}
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.48\textwidth}

''''''
\end{subtable}

'''

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{title6}
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.48\textwidth}

''''''

\end{subtable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please clarify what "some [subtables] go beyond the margin" entails. E.g., are they much wider than `0.48\textwidth`? What's in those `subtable` environments -- a `tabular` environment, a `tabularx` environment, or something else? Do you allow line-breaking in the cells of the tabular-like environments?

Comment: See, if the second example in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477813/putting-15-images-in-5-rows-2x2-32-1-on-side can help you.