# Main figure label as prefix of subcaption

Tags: graphics, floats, captions, subfloats, subcaption

I have a figure with multiple large subfigures spanning multiple pages, following the syntax from this nicely written answer:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/278748

The figure and sub-figure captions are in this configuration:

```
[Page 1]
(a) Subfigure a caption
Figure 1

[Page 2]
(b) Subfigure b caption
Figure 1
...
```

I want the main figure label to appear as the prefix of the subfigure captions, something like this:

```
[Page 1]
Figure 1 (a) Subfigure a caption

[Page 2]
Figure 1 (b) Subfigure b caption
...
```

I have tried playing around with the placement of caption and subcaption command. No success so far.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a small complete document, which we can compile how it is and which reproduce your problem. See, if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477813/  can help you

Comment: And v document preamble add `\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{Figure~\arabic{figure}~(\alph{subfigure})}`. However, your question is not entirely clear, so please again, provide MWE (Minimal Working Example).