# Two subfigures, two pages, tikz images

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, subfloats, subcaption

I have a large tikz flow diagram that spans multiple pages.  I broke it up into an 'a' and 'b' figure.  It would be nice if the caption would state 'Figure 1a:' and 'Figure 1b:' automatically (instead of just 'Figure 1:' for both).  Also, I would like the references in the text to work automatically as well (as 1a and 1b without have to state 'a' and 'b' explicitly as I did below).  I have tried the subfigure and subcaption packages but to no avail. Each should have 1 unique caption. Here is a MWE.

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{caption,tikz}
\begin{document}

Would like this to automatically be listed as
Figures~\ref{fig1a}a and~\ref{fig1b}b in text and caption.

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) -- (10,  0) -- (10,-12) -- (0,-12) -- (0,0);
    \draw (0, 0) -- (10,-12);
    \draw (10,0) -- ( 0,-12);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Figure 1a}
  \label{fig1a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) -- (10,  0) -- (10,-12) -- (0,-12) -- (0,0);
    \draw (0, 0) -- (10,-12);
    \draw (10,0) -- ( 0,-12);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Figure 1b}
  \label{fig1b}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

A second question, probably should be a separate question, what should I be using: figure, caption, subfigure, or subcaption?  I have read on other threads that all but subcaption are deprecated, but when I use subcaption with the required document class (not included), I get the following.

> Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
>   (caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
>   See the caption package documentation for explanation.

Does my document class need too be updated?  Can anyone clear this up?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which problem are you referring to @Zarko?  I assume the warning, but how is that related to graphics.sty?

Comment: Ups, i misread your example, sorry. Anyway, I can't reproduce your problem,

Comment: If I correctly understood your question, than it is duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages/278748#278748

Comment: @Zerko, that's not exactly what I would like.  The solution in that link has a caption for the first 2 subfigures and a subcaption for each, plus a caption for the second two subfigures and a caption for that two.  I would like 1 caption for the first 'subfigure' on the first page (labeled as Fig 1a), and a caption for the second subfigure on the second page (labeled as Fig. 1b).  If I use the solution there, I get one figure on the first page labeled only as (a) and the second figure labeled as (b).  If I turn the subcaptions into captions, they are both 1, and 1 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the `a` and `b` are already in the labels.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{caption,tikz}
\begin{document}

Would like this to automatically be listed as
Figures~\ref{fig1a} and~\ref{fig1b} in text and caption.

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) -- (10,  0) -- (10,-12) -- (0,-12) -- (0,0);
    \draw (0, 0) -- (10,-12);
    \draw (10,0) -- ( 0,-12);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \def\thefigure{\arabic{figure}a}
  \caption{Figure 1a}
  \label{fig1a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) -- (10,  0) -- (10,-12) -- (0,-12) -- (0,0);
    \draw (0, 0) -- (10,-12);
    \draw (10,0) -- ( 0,-12);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \def\thefigure{\arabic{figure}b}
  \caption{Figure 1b}
  \label{fig1b}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes but because of the \ContinuedFloat, they are both references at Fig.1

Comment: I only just now noticed the '\def\thefigure' line.  That worked perfectly!