# Can I automatically break a long `displayquote` within `figure` across multiple pages?

Tags: floats, captions, page-breaking, csquotes

I have a `figure` environment containing a `displayquote` environment. The text is too long to fit on a single page, even if I change the text size (which I have been able to do elsewhere).

However, the `displayquote` does not break at the bottom of the page and instead just runs off it. See:

[image: MWE]

There are some similar questions (e.g., [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages)), which involve `figure`s made up of `subfigure`s, but I only have a single `displayquote` so these aren't applicable here.

So far, the best I've been able to do is to split it across multiple `figure`s, with `\clearpage`s between them.

This feels like a bit of a hack though, and results in the final chunk of the text being vertically-centered, even with `[t!]` on its `figure` (although this isn't happening with my MWE so I'm not sure where the behaviour is coming from).

Is there any way I can just have a single `figure`, with a single `displayquote`, that will automatically split itself across multiple pages? Even better, can I do so whilst automatically appending some sort of ‘continued on following page’ note to the end of each page?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}  
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

    % Issue
    
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{displayquote}
            \Blindtext
            \Blindtext
        \end{displayquote}
        \caption{Caption}
    \end{figure}
    
    %% Hacky fix
    
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{displayquote}
            \blindtext
            
            \blindtext
            
            \blindtext
        \end{displayquote}
    \end{figure}
    
    \clearpage
    
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{displayquote}
            \blindtext
        \end{displayquote}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
        \label{fig:testlabel}
    \end{figure}
    
    Hey look at fig.~\ref{fig:testlabel}. % Should be `fig. 1'

\end{document}
```

Comment: A `figure` construction is single page only. Why are you placing it inside a `figure` in the first place? You are not even using a caption.

Comment: @daleif I'm including a series of emails, which are then referenced elsewhere as figs. I *am* using a caption, and I have one in the MWE (in the 'Hacky fix' bit, and I've just added one to the 'Issue' bit to make it even clearer)

Comment: You will probably need to use a different construction. By design figures cannot be broken. You might want to look at the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package if you insist on referring to these as figures.