# Images out of margins

Tags: floats, margins

I have the problem that by inserting 4 large images they do not fit in a single sheet (see attached image and code used).
I would like that, if all the images don't fit on one sheet, they go to the next sheet.

How can I do?
Thank you

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subfigure[Intero dominio] {
            \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{\jpgfigspath 2DMeshLontano}
            \label{fig:2DMeshLontano}
            }
        \hspace{0.5cm}
        \subfigure[Rotore] {
            \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{\jpgfigspath 2DMeshNormale}
            \label{fig:2DMeshNormale}
            }
        \hspace{0.5cm}
        \subfigure[Intorno della pala] {
            \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{\jpgfigspath 2DMeshRavvicinato}
            \label{fig:2DMeshRavvicinato}
            }
            \hspace{0.5cm}
        \subfigure[Profilo della pala] {
            \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{\jpgfigspath 2DMeshVicino}
            \label{fig:2DMeshVicino}
            }
        \caption{Griglia di calcolo 2D (vista dall'alto)}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: you have horizontal space         \hspace{0.5cm} which can not do anything as you are making all the images  more than half of text width so you can only have one per line. If you want them stacked vertically make them smaller so they fit, or if you want two on each row make them smaller (less than .5\textwidth) so they fit

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ,  What if I want to have 3 on one page and 1 on the next page?

Comment: see float package and `\ContinuedFloat` (many examples on this site)

Comment: With `\ContinuedFloat` (also caption package) and figure[bp] (first) and [pt] (rest), you can even add one subfigure per float.

Comment: Mi advice: reduce the  width of figures to `.45/textwidth`, remove `\centering` and change the `\hspace`s by `\hfill` to have a 2x2 subfigures instead of 3+1.

Comment: What I need is not to fit the 4 images on one page. I would like to enlarge them at will without necessarily all being on one page. I want them to go to the next page automatically if there is no more space (with the relative caption under the last image)

Comment: @Alessandro imho then is better 4 figures in 4 floats with 4 independent captions. Three images with only a subcaption in one page, and later one image alone with caption plus a subcaption in other page only can confuse to the reader, specially if pages are not even-odd in a two side document.

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages/278748#278748 can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method for extra long figures that I have used:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \subfloat[subfigure caption]{\includegraphics[]{fig1.eps}\\
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[]{fig2.eps}\\
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[]{fig3.eps}\\
 \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
\addtocounter{subfigure}{3}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[]{fig4.eps}\\
    \caption{Figure caption}
  \end{figure}
```

In this example, I use the subfig package. End the figure at your third figure and start a new figure environment for the next figure. The `\addtocounter` command makes sure that the subfigure numbering resumes from where it left off in the previous figure. Here, the number is three as you have three figures in the first figure environment.

An alternative is to have the figures beside each other by removing the newline (`\\`) symbol for the even numbered figures and setting the width to, say `\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]`. Then you have all the figures on one page.