# Long table can not starts in the same page with a two column text

Tags: longtable, two-column, article

How to start a long table in the same page with a two column text article?
I have a long table within a two column text article. I want to draw a long table starting in the same page with the text or after a paragraph, but it is move to the next top page. This is my MWE. Please help.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}  
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, xltabular}  
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}  
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}  
\lipsum[1-2]  
\onecolumn  
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} lX @{}}  
    \caption{Descriptions of learning styles}  
    \label{learningstyles}  \\
    \toprule
\thead{Learning\\ Style}  & \thead{Description}         \\  
    \midrule  
\endfirsthead  
    \caption[]{Descriptions of learning styles (cont.)} \\  
    \toprule  
\thead{Learning\\ Style}  & \thead{Description}         \\  
    \midrule  
\endhead  
    \midrule  
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{%  
        \footnotesize\textit{Continue on the next page}}\\      
\endfoot  
    \bottomrule  
\endlastfoot  
1. Visual 
    &   People who understand work better when it is in the form of a diagram. Knowledge and concept maps are good tools for such learners.\\
    \addlinespace
2. Aurala
    &   People who dislike reading, but enjoys hearing someone else say something aloud. Hearing the information is key for such students and group discussions can be of great aid.\\
    \addlinespace
3. Verbal
    &   Verbal learners are people who express themselves easier through writing and speaking. Mnemonics, scripting and role playing are some great techniques to helps those learners.\\
    \addlinespace
4. Physical
    &   Hands-on activities rather than lectures or demonstrations appeal to these learners. They are a small percentage of the population, but they learn better through practical experience.\\
    \addlinespace
5. Logical
    &   People who are good with numbers and using logic to understand. They easily recognize patterns and often tend to group information to further their understanding.\\
    \addlinespace
6. Social
    &   When communicating and socialising with others come easy, someone is a social learner. Studying in group formats and learning from others are their speciality and is how they excel.\\
    \addlinespace
7. Solitary
    &   People who are more comfortable studying in private and introspective.  The concentration of these students are at their peak when they can focus on their own thoughts without the distractions of others around them.\\  

\end{xltabular}  
\twocolumn  
\lipsum[1-3]  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your table is moved to the next page since \onecolumn starts a new page.

Comment: Is a table really the best way to display this kind of information? Probably a simple enumerate-like list would also work here?

Comment: Does your table is really longer than one page? If not, why you not enclose it in `table*` float? If it is longer, than tray to split it  manually   in two parts and than using `table*`  similarly as is done in   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages/278748#278748.

Comment: almost all tables set using `lX` can be better set as a description list. longtable does not support twocolumn so yiu have to switch to one column, and a new page.