# Split figure environment across pages

Tags: floats, page-breaking, subfloats

Good evening guys,

I am currently trying to figure out how to add a custom pagebreak inside a figure environment containing multiple subfloats (2 columns) using the subfig package, e.g.:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[][1] {
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{...}
    }
    \qquad
    \subfloat[][2]{
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{...}
    }

    \subfloat[][3]{
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{...}
    }
    \qquad
    \subfloat[][4] {
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{...}
    }

    \subfloat[][5]{
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{...}
    }
    \qquad
    \subfloat[][6]{
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{...}
    }

    \subfloat[][7] {
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{...}
    }
    \qquad
    \subfloat[][8]{
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{...}
    }

    \subfloat[][9]{
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{...}
    }
    \qquad
    \subfloat[][10] {
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{...}
    }
    \caption{...}
    \label{...}
\end{figure}
```

I have tried inserting `\pagebreak`, `\newpage`, and `\clearpage` between figure 2 and 3 to split the figure across two pages, but none of them worked. Is this even possible? What is the best way to achieve this?

Thank you all!

Comment: You cannot split float over pages. For solution see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages/278748#278748. Actually, your question is duplicate to question in the given link.

Comment: Thank you guys. In the meantime, I found the solution by myself. (see my own answer to the question below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... found the solution.

`\ContinuedFloat` did the trick.

Example:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[][1] {
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{...}
    }
    \qquad
    \subfloat[][2]{
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{...}
    }
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \ContinuedFloat
    \subfloat[][3]{
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{...}
    }
    \qquad
    \subfloat[][4] {
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{...}
    }
    \caption{...}
\end{figure}
```