# Subfigure numbering issue with \ContinuedFloat in Latex

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I have three figures need to be separated into two pages so I'm using `\ContinuedFloat` with `subfigure` package. The resulting label is (a)(b) and then (after `\ContinuedFloat`) (a) again instead of (a)(b)(c).

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[Subfigure caption 1.]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{img1.png}
        \label{fig:img1}
    }\\
    \vspace{40pt}
    \subfigure[Subfigure caption 2.]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{img2.png}
        \label{fig:img2}
    }
    \caption{Figure caption.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
    \subfigure[Subfigure caption 3.]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{img3.png}
        \label{fig:img3}
    }
    \caption{Figure caption.}
    \label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}
```

Have been trying out multiple online solutions but didn't get lucky. Help is really appreciated!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages/278748#278748, i suspect that you question is duplicate to question in link.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. However the referenced post uses `subcaption` package while I'm using `subfigure`. I have my whole dissertation written with `subfigure` without realizing that it is deprecated. Changing to `subcaption` would be a huge amount of extra work.

Comment: You should be aware, that `subfigure` package is deprecated (and not maintained) and  replaced by `subfig` package which define `\subfloat` comand for inserting image in figure.  Newest `subcaption` packages is among them most powerful.  I strongly suggest you, than instead of `subfigure` package use `subcaption`. By this you will  avoid to bunch of unexpected problems as is one, which you faced now.

Comment: Thanks! This worked like wonders for me. I didn't know it is an easy fix going from `subfigure` to `subfig`.  Really appreciate the help and I sure won't be using `subfigure` again.

Comment: Regardless that `subfig` resolve many `subfigure` issues it still has some drawbacks which are  solved in `subcaption` package. Anyway, `subfig` is solid package. Can we conclude that your problem is solved and close your question as solved by comments?

Comment: Yep the issue is resolved. Really appreciate your support!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because problem was solved by comments