# Page break between two images

Tags: table-of-contents, graphics, captions, page-breaking, subfloats

I'd like to have a page break between two images.
Image `A` should be on the first page.
Both images `A` and `B` should have one common caption which
should only be shown under the image `B` AND one subcaption (`A` and `B`).

What I've tried so far:

```
\documentclass[
    pdftex,a4paper,11pt,oneside,fleqn,
    bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,
    headlines=2.1,headsepline,
    numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}

%%%----- Pakete ---------------------------------
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.2cm,right=2.2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}           % Grafiken einbinden
\usepackage{xcolor}                             % Farben ermöglichen
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfig}
    
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure.\arabic{subfigure}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon,
    listofformat=subsimple}
\captionsetup{lofdepth=2}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{}
\makeatother

%%%----- Mathe ----------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage[squaren,textstyle]{SIunits}
\usepackage{icomma}
    
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{trfsigns}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,float}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Ordnungsspektrum über der Zeit]{
        \label{fig: Ordnungsspektrum_vs_time_ANC24}
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Beschleunigungspegelverlauf der 24. Ordnung]{
        \label{fig: Ordungsschnitt_24}%
        \includegraphics{example-image-b}}%
    \caption{Reduktion des Körperschalls in der 24. Ordnung bei einer konstanten Drehzahl von 300 rpm; Narrowband-FxLMS-Algorithmus inaktiv für $0 \leq t \leq 23 \, \text{s}$ und aktiv für $23 \, \text{s} < t \leq 45 \, \text{s}$}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-c}
  \caption{example image c}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures  

\end{document}
```

The list of figures should still look like this:

```
1. Reduktion des Körperschalls in der 24. Ordnung bei einer konstanten Drehzahl
von 300 rpm; Narrowband-FxLMS-Algorithmus inaktiv f ̈ur 0 ≤ t ≤ 23 s und
aktiv f ̈ur 23 s < t ≤ 45 s
     1.1 Ordnungsspektrum über der Zeit
     1.2 Beschleunigungspegelverlauf der 24. Ordnung
2. example image c
```

Comment: But you have page break between both figures and listof figures is as you like to have.. However,  images in the first figure are to big that they can be placed on the first page, where you have some text, so it is pushed to the next page. Be aware, that floats cannot be broken between pages.

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages/278748#278748 is close to what you after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
Considered is `siunitx` and their definitions of quantities.

- Your question is not entirely clear.
- I guess, that you looking for something like shown in [Split subfigures over multiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages/278748#278748).
- Adoption answer in the given link to your case is:

```
\documentclass[
    pdftex,a4paper,11pt,oneside,fleqn,
    bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,
    headlines=2.1,headsepline,
    numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}

%%%----- Pakete ---------------------------------
\usepackage[a4paper,
            hmargin={3.2cm,2.2cm}, vmargin=1.5cm,
            includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}       % Grafiken einbinden
\usepackage{xcolor}         % Farben ermöglichen
\usepackage{caption}        % Fuer \ContinuedFloat
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure.\arabic{subfigure}}
\captionsetup{lofdepth=2}

%%%----- Mathe ----------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,bm}
%\usepackage[squaren,textstyle]{SIunits}% it is obsolete, use `siunitx` instead
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{icomma}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{trfsigns}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,float}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[!b]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Ordnungsspektrum über der Zeit]{
        \label{fig: Ordnungsspektrum_vs_time_ANC24}
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
    \subfloat[Beschleunigungspegelverlauf der 24. Ordnung]{
        \label{fig: Ordungsschnitt_24}%
        \includegraphics{example-image-b}}%
    \caption{Reduktion des Körperschalls in der 24. Ordnung bei einer konstanten Drehzahl von \qty{300}{rpm}; Narrowband-FxLMS-Algorithmus inaktiv für $0 \leq t \leq \qty{23}{\second}$ und aktiv für $\qty{23}{\second} < t \leq \qty{45}{\second}$}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-c}
  \caption{example image c}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-5]

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

- List of figures is as you wish.
- Image A is on the first page,
- Images B and C follows on the next pages
- In comparison to your MWE, above are used

  - `subcaption` package instead of `subfig`,
  - `caption` package instead of `capt-of`.
    It is needed for macro `\ContinuedFloat`.

I hope that result of compilation is what you after:

[image]

[image]

**Addendum:**

- For showing of subcaption in LoF you need to replace code line `\captionsetup{lofdepth=2}` width

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}
```

- But, than you will faced with catch "on which page is figure 1?":  on the first, where is subfigure 1.1 or on the second, where is the subfigure 1.2.
- This is important, how will LoF looks.

  - I suspect, that you like to have the following form of LoF:

[image]

but in this case, you need to rewrite the figures code as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[!b]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Ordnungsspektrum über der Zeit]{
        \label{fig: Ordnungsspektrum_vs_time_ANC24}
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \caption[Reduktion des Körperschalls in der 24. Ordnung bei einer konstanten Drehzahl von \qty{300}{rpm}; Narrowband-FxLMS-Algorithmus inaktiv für $0 \leq t \leq \qty{23}{\second}$ und aktiv für $\qty{23}{\second} < t \leq \qty{45}{\second}$]{(continued on the next page)}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
    \subfloat[Beschleunigungspegelverlauf der 24. Ordnung]{
        \label{fig: Ordungsschnitt_24}%
        \includegraphics{example-image-b}}%
    \caption[]{Reduktion des Körperschalls in der 24. Ordnung bei einer konstanten Drehzahl von \qty{300}{rpm}; Narrowband-FxLMS-Algorithmus inaktiv für $0 \leq t \leq \qty{23}{\second}$ und aktiv für $\qty{23}{\second} < t \leq \qty{45}{\second}$}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-c}
  \caption{Example image c}
\end{figure}
```

and will appear in documents as

[image]

- in the case, that you not liked that "Figure 1" is shown below first subimage, than just use original code, but then the LoF will be:

[image]

- In your MWE you use `H` figure positioning specifier. As you see, in my MWE I replaced them with `[!b]` and `[!t]`. With this are enabled, that figure can float. This means, that you can merge both subimages in one figure, which will show in page 2, and left space on page 1 for other text in document (for this floats are intended). But this is all up to you.

Comment: Why is figure `1.1` and figure `1.2` not mentioned in the list of figures?

Comment: @Domi1908, i overlooked this. However,there  is problem, how you like that subfigure are listed in LoF. It standard they are listed in the same order as are in document. In your case that first bi shown subfigure 1.1, than figure 1 followed by subfigure 2.  See addendum to answer (it will appear ASAP).

Comment: @Domi1908, see addendum. There is some explanation, what is possible.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much @Zarko