# Split Subfigures over pages without \subcaption using a thesis template

Tags: subfloats, templates

I am using the [`fauthesis.cls`](http://physics2.fau.edu/%7Ecbeetle/FAUThesis/) for writing up my dissertation.  I am having an issue splitting subfigures figures across pages as I cannot seem to use the `\subcaption` option.  I get the error message"

> ! Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation
> (subcaption)                with the subfigure package.

I found another option that does not give me the error, however, the subfigures do not break across the pages.  Can you tell me how I can split subfigures across pages working along the [`fauthesis.cls`](http://physics2.fau.edu/%7Ecbeetle/FAUThesis/)?

Here is my code that does not break the subfigures:

```
\documentclass[phd, 12pt, print]{fauthesis}

\title{Excellent Title}
\author{The Boss Man}
\gender{M}
\graduation{December}{2022}
\department{Fire}
\college{College of Super Heros}
\chair{Dr. Who That}
\dean{Dr. Who That}
\deantitle{Dean}
\dgc{Robin Jr.}[Ph.D.]

\advisor{Super Man}
\supervisor{Spider Man}
\supervisor{Bat Man}
\supervisor{Aqua Man}



\signaturepush{-2.0}                                        %   Increase or decrease the vertical gap between committee and administration signatures

%======================================================================================
%  ADDITIONS
%======================================================================================
% For Tables
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,bm,mathtools}

%####################     FOR FIGURES        ################
\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\begin{figure}
\centering     %%% not \center
\subfigure[Figure A]{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-a}}
\subfigure[Figure B]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-b}}
\subfigure[Figure C]{\label{fig:c}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-a}}
\subfigure[Figure D]{\label{fig:d}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-b}}
\subfigure[Figure E]{\label{fig:e}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-b}}
\subfigure[Figure F]{\label{fig:f}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-b}}
\subfigure[Figure G]{\label{fig:g}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-b}}
\subfigure[Figure H]{\label{fig:h}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-b}}
\subfigure[Figure I]{\label{fig:i}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-b}}
\subfigure[Figure J]{\label{fig:j}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-b}}
\caption{my caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**NOTE: With this option however, I lose the formatting setting for the caption** found in the [`fauthesis.cls`](http://physics2.fau.edu/%7Ecbeetle/FAUThesis/) found from lines 1377:

```
%%% Caption Formatting
%
% This modifies the default LaTeX format for figure and table captions.
%   Single-line captions are set centered under the figure.
%   Multi-line captions are set centered in a paragraph of width \capwidth.
%
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
    \vskip\abovecaptionskip
    \sbox\@tempboxa{\small{\bfseries #1\/}: #2}%
    \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa > \capwidth
        \@tempdima=\textwidth%
        \advance\@tempdima by -\capwidth%
        \advance\leftskip by 0.5\@tempdima%
        \advance\rightskip by 0.5\@tempdima%
        \singlespacing
        {\bfseries #1\/}: #2\par
    \else
        \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
    \fi
    \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
%
% The default \capwidth is 80% of the \textwidth.
%
\newlength{\capwidth}
\setlength{\capwidth}{0.8\textwidth}
```

How to maintain this formatting using the `subcaption` option or is there an easier way to do the splitting of the subfigures across pages using this `fauthesis.cls`?

Thanks in advance for your help and time!

Comment: See, if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages/278748#278748 can help you.

Comment: Floats cannot be broken over several pages.`subfigure` and  `subcaption` packages are not compatible.  `subfigure` is obsolete, don't use it. Instead it us `subfig`, which sytax can be emulated by `subcaption` (version 1.3 or later).

Comment: @Zarko, thanks!  Your link does help with the breaking of the subplots, but my Figure caption specs get lost.  How do I maintain the `fauthesis.cls` caption text specs like the spacing and bold font?  Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't  `fauthesis.cls` (and not intend to download it), so I'm not familiar with it and its caption settings. Sorry, regarding it I can't help you

Comment: I posted the section of the code formatting the figure/caption below the Note.  Does that assist you in converging to a solution using your suggestion?