# Split images in a figure into two pages

Tags: graphics, floats, includegraphics

I have 3 images put in one figure with different subcaptions. To create this figures, I have not used `subfigure` or `minipage`. But I would like to split the images in the Figure over two pages. The code written is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Case 2.1}{\includegraphics[width=0.350\textwidth]{./Pictures/a.jpg}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Case 2.2}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{./Pictures/b.jpg}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Case 2.3}{\includegraphics[width=0.50\textwidth]{./Pictures/c.jpg}}%
\vspace*{1mm}
\caption{Alphabets}
\end{figure}
```

I want the images (a) and (b) in one page and (c) in another page. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: **Remark:** Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738 for how to use example pictures in questions so that everybody can recreate your problem without needing your image files: Boils down to `\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} ` :)

Comment: Two pages would require two separate figure environments (b then t).  See \ContinuedFloat from the caption package.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages/278748#278748. If you like to have figures in instead subfigures, than replace °`subfigure` with `minipage`. Fore more help, extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can test as it is.