# How to control subfigures through pages?

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

I am trying to place multiple subfigures into 3 columns. I have large no. of figures to display. Naturally, keeping the figures visible for readers in an article, I am trying to fit 9 or 12 figures in a page. But using subfigures, the figures are entering footer zone and in the margin area. How to overcome this such that it does not happen. Suggest a way to arrange the figures such that they are presented beautifully throughout multiple pages.

My Code is given below:
(for 12 images) The `float`, `subcaption`, `caption`, `graphicx` all the packages are there in preamble.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{images/bfly-primary/2.png}
    \caption{2 by 2}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{images/bfly-primary/3.png}
    \caption{3 by 3}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{images/bfly-primary/4.png}
    \caption{4 by 4}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{images/bfly-primary/5.png}
    \caption{5 by 5}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{images/bfly-primary/6.png}
    \caption{6 by 6}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{images/bfly-primary/7.png}
    \caption{7 by 7}
\end{subfigure}


\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{images/bfly-primary/8.png}
    \caption{8 by 8}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{images/bfly-primary/9.png}
    \caption{9 by 9}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{images/bfly-primary/10.png}
    \caption{10 by 10}
\end{subfigure}


\begin{subfigure}[hb]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{images/bfly-primary/11.png}
    \caption{11 by 11}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[hb]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{images/bfly-primary/12.png}
    \caption{12 by 12}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[hb]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{images/bfly-primary/15p.png}
    \caption{15 by 15}
\end{subfigure}


\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{images/bfly-primary/20p.png}
    \caption{20 by 20}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{images/bfly-primary/25p.png}
    \caption{25 by 25}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{images/bfly-primary/30p.png}
    \caption{30 by 30}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

[image: This is the output I am getting]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See, if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages/278748#278748 can help you.

Comment: Please post code we can compile to reproduce the problem. You can use, for example, `example-image` in place of `1.png` etc. (If necessary, you can specify both the width and height since it doesn't matter if the example image gets distorted.)

Comment: Off-topic: None of the 16 [!] `\centering` directives to anything useful. Delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But using subfigures, the figures are entering footer zone and in the margin area.

You need to specify a target width for the graphs. I suggest you choose `\linewidth` as the target width, stated in the optional argument of `\includegraphics`. And, unless your paper size is unusually tall, there's no way that 5 rows of graphs will fit on a single page. I suggest you place 4 rows of graphs on one page, and 1 more row of graphs on the next page, using a `\ContinuedFloat` directive at the beginning of the second `figure` environment, to continue both the figure and the subfigure numbering.

[image]

Be sure to omit the `demo` document class option in your real document.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
% or maybe \usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p!]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,height=1.8in} % global placement options

\caption{Some graphics}
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/2.png}
    \caption{2 by 2}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/3.png}
    \caption{3 by 3}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}  
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/4.png}
    \caption{4 by 4}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}   
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/5.png}
    \caption{5 by 5}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/6.png}`
    \caption{6 by 6}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/7.png}
    \caption{7 by 7}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/8.png}
    \caption{8 by 8}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}  
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/9.png}
    \caption{9 by 9}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}  
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/10.png}
    \caption{10 by 10}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/11.png}
    \caption{11 by 11}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/12.png}
    \caption{12 by 12}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}  
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/15p.png}
    \caption{15 by 15}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}
\clearpage

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\ContinuedFloat
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,height=1.8in} % global placement options

\caption{Some graphics, cont'd}

\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/20p.png}
    \caption{20 by 20}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/25p.png}
    \caption{25 by 25}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/30p.png}
    \caption{30 by 30}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}


\lipsum[1-2]  % filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a section heading, but when compiled  the entire pages after the section heading is left blank. What should I do to make the set up flexible, so that if there is space to fit only 6 or 9 or even 3, it only places 3 or 6 or 9 images only and continue to next page for the remaining images ?

Comment: @aminitindas - Try placing just three rows in the first rows in the first `figure`, and change `[p]` to `[h]`.

Comment: Thanks. And can they be flexible depending upon the space left in the page? They can't, right ? Or is there any way ?

Comment: @aminitindas - Since you've provided exactly zero information about your document setup (e.g., paper size? margin widths?, font size?), I'm not in a position to give advice of the variety you appear to be seeking. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Using `\ContinuedFloat` (caption package) one can place each row into a separate float.  Insetad of `\medskip` the rows will be separated by `\floatsep`.  This offers a bit more flexibility in placement.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
% or maybe \usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[bp]
\caption{Some graphics}
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/2.png}
    \caption{2 by 2}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/3.png}
    \caption{3 by 3}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}  
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/4.png}
    \caption{4 by 4}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tbp!]
\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}   
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/5.png}
    \caption{5 by 5}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/6.png}`
    \caption{6 by 6}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/7.png}
    \caption{7 by 7}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tbp!]
\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/8.png}
    \caption{8 by 8}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}  
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/9.png}
    \caption{9 by 9}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}  
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/10.png}
    \caption{10 by 10}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tbp!]
\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/11.png}
    \caption{11 by 11}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/12.png}
    \caption{12 by 12}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}  
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/15p.png}
    \caption{15 by 15}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tbp!]
\ContinuedFloat

\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/20p.png}
    \caption{20 by 20}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/25p.png}
    \caption{25 by 25}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/30p.png}
    \caption{30 by 30}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

---

This version uses `\label` and `\pageref` to automate a "Continue from page ..." notice.  It takes two runs to work (aux file).

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
% or maybe \usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\usepackage{refcount}% or hyperref
\newcounter{figurerow}[figure]

\newcommand{\ContinuedNotice}{%
  \edef\lastpage{\getpagerefnumber{fig.\thefigure.\thefigurerow}}%
  \refstepcounter{figurerow}%
  \label{fig.\thefigure.\thefigurerow}%
  \edef\thispage{\getpagerefnumber{fig.\thefigure.\thefigurerow}}%
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{fig.\thefigure.1}=\thispage\relax
  \else
    \ifnum\lastpage=\thispage\relax
    \else
      \centerline{Continued from page \lastpage}
      \par\medskip
    \fi
  \fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[bp]
\caption{Some graphics}
\ContinuedNotice% setup
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/2.png}
    \caption{2 by 2}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/3.png}
    \caption{3 by 3}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}  
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/4.png}
    \caption{4 by 4}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tbp!]
\ContinuedFloat
\ContinuedNotice
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}   
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/5.png}
    \caption{5 by 5}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/6.png}`
    \caption{6 by 6}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/7.png}
    \caption{7 by 7}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tbp!]
\ContinuedFloat
\ContinuedNotice
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/8.png}
    \caption{8 by 8}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}  
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/9.png}
    \caption{9 by 9}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}  
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/10.png}
    \caption{10 by 10}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tbp!]
\ContinuedFloat
\ContinuedNotice
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/11.png}
    \caption{11 by 11}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/12.png}
    \caption{12 by 12}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}  
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/15p.png}
    \caption{15 by 15}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tbp!]
\ContinuedFloat
\ContinuedNotice
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/20p.png}
    \caption{20 by 20}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/25p.png}
    \caption{25 by 25}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{images/bfly-primary/30p.png}
    \caption{30 by 30}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```