continue subfig in the next page
I have hundreds of feynman graphs in the subfigure environment. The code is the following:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol} % Allows for multiple columns
\usepackage[squaren,Gray]{SIunits}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage[textsize=tiny,backgroundcolor=white]{todonotes}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
\feynmandiagram[small]{%diagram_number_1
3 -- [ anti fermion,color=violet ] 1,
 2 -- [ anti fermion,color=violet,quarter right ] 3,
3 -- [ boson,color=blue,quarter right ] 2,
ext2 [particle=] -- [fermion,color=red] 1,
ext1 [particle=] -- [boson,color=blue] 1,
ext4 [particle=] -- [anti fermion,color=violet] 2,
};
\caption*{dia 1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
\feynmandiagram[small]{%diagram_number_2
1 -- [ anti fermion,color=violet ] 3,
 3 -- [ anti fermion,color=violet,quarter right ] 2,
3 -- [ boson,color=blue,quarter left ] 2,
ext4 [particle=] -- [anti fermion,color=violet] 1,
ext1 [particle=] -- [boson,color=blue] 1,
ext2 [particle=] -- [fermion,color=red] 2,
};
\caption*{dia 2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

where I have pasted two such diagrams. But when I have 50 such diagrams, it goes out of the page and does not continue on the next page. How to change this? I tried ContinuedFloat following some previous posts but it does not work at all for me.

Maybe some kind of long table would be better suited? For example from the longtable package or from tabularray

See, if solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages/278748#278748 is acceptble to you.

\ContinuedFloat gives error. Not working for me

I doubt in your claim in above comment. Do you load caption package? As you can see in link (and if you tested it), it works.

You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689854/how-to-control-subfigures-through-pages/689897?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C12.8561#689897 useful.

@Zarko subcaption loads caption, I think?

How did you try to use \ContinuedFloat and how did it not work? Did you get an error?

@cfr, you are right. I overlooked that in OP in his document load subcaption package. However, I don't know, how (s)he tested my suggestion.

@Zarko Oh, indeed. There is no clue here as to how the test was done or how it failed. As far as I know all \ContinuedFloat really does is adjust the counter? I wonder if the OP is expecting it to break the figure automatically. As far as I know, there isn't a package to do that, which maybe why a longtable or similar was suggested above. (But, obviously, that won't float ....)

@cfr, \ContinuedFloat prevent caption counter that be incremented, but not influence on subcaption counter.

@Zarko Oh, thanks. I didn't know/had forgotten that. I very rarely use a continuation float. (I have used one at least once, but not sure about twice!)

@Zarko Are you sure? AFAIK \ContinuedFloat prevents the subfigure counter from being reset additionally, so after \ContinuedFloat the subfigure counter continues from the previous figure.
