# Subfigure over two pages with text above and below

Tags: positioning, figure-placement

My subfigure consists of 5 single images, 2 in each line. Before and after comes text. When I try to split it, the first two images end up at the bottom of the page instead of directly under the text (see image).
Is there a way that there is not so much space without me having to make the images smaller?

```
\begin{figure}[!b]
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{figures/ErsterSchritt_ml.png}
         \caption{Erster Schritt nach \Gls{perturbation}}
         \label{fig:ersterSchrittml}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hspace{3cm}
     \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{figures/ZweiterSchritt_ml.png}
         \caption{Zweiter Schritt nach \Gls{perturbation}}
         \label{fig:zweiterSchrittml}
     \end{subfigure}
     %\\
     \end{figure}%
  \begin{figure}[ht]
  \ContinuedFloat
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{figures/DritterSchritt_ml.png}
         \caption{Zweiter Schritt nach \Gls{perturbation}}
         \label{fig:dritterSchrittml}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hspace{3cm}
     \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{figures/VierterSchritt_ml.png}
         \caption{Vierter Schritt nach \Gls{perturbation}}
         \label{fig:vierterSchrittml}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     %\\
     \end{figure}%
  \begin{figure}[ht]
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
     \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{figures/FuenfterSchritt_ml.png}
         \caption{Fünfter Schritt nach \Gls{perturbation}}
         \label{fig:fuenfterSchrittml}
     \end{subfigure}  
        \caption{Mittelwerte der \Glsxtrshort{mos}-\glsxtrshort{ml} [mm] der Assessments. Es wird unterschieden nach Richtung der \Gls{perturbation} und Zeitpunkt des Assessments. Untersucht wurden die ersten fünf Schritte nach Auftreten einer \Gls{perturbation}}
        \label{fig:fuenfSchritteml}
\end{figure}

\newpage
Bei Untersuchung des ersten Schrittes nach Auftreten einer \Gls{perturbation} zeigt sich, dass die \Glsxtrshort{mos}-\glsxtrshort{ap} bei \Gls{perturbation}en nach vorne beim ersten Laufband-Assessment zum Zeitpunkt T0 eine größere Streuung hat, als zu allen anderen Zeitpunkten und Richtungen (siehe Abbildung \ref{fig:assessments_ersterSchrittAp}). Die Werte während des ersten Laufband-Assessments T0 haben eine größere Streuung als die des zweiten Laufband-Assessments T0 und des Laufband-Assessments T14. \\
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Unfortunately nobody can copy and compile your code: please try yourself and add, what's missing. Thank you

Comment: By starting on the bottom [b!], you avoid getting text between the figures.  You could use a smaller font in the captions.  \footnotesize is popular.  I would use \hfil or \hfill instead of \hspace.

Comment: See, if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages/278748#278748 can elp you. To my opinion your question is duplicate to question in above link.

Answer (score 0):

Since you had some free space in the last row, I moved some of the subcaptions (text) there.  Also, you need to add `[b!]` to every figure which might wind up on the first page, and the `[h]` is redundant since every float is either at the bottom or top of a page.

The `\makebox` keeps the spacing constant across the rows, but may cause overlapping.  Then again, `0.3\textwidth` is proabably too small anyway.  You might wan to use `\subfloat` instead, or `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}[!b]
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{figures/ErsterSchritt_ml.png}
         \caption{}\label{fig:ersterSchrittml}
     \end{subfigure}%
     \hfil
     \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{figures/ZweiterSchritt_ml.png}
         \caption{}\label{fig:zweiterSchrittml}
     \end{subfigure}
     \end{figure}%
  \begin{figure}[tb!]
  \ContinuedFloat
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{figures/DritterSchritt_ml.png}
         \caption{}\label{fig:dritterSchrittml}
     \end{subfigure}%
     \hfil
     \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{figures/VierterSchritt_ml.png}
         \caption{}
         \label{fig:vierterSchrittml}
     \end{subfigure}
     \end{figure}%
  \begin{figure}[t]% if they all fit on ome page, you wouldn't be doing this
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{figures/FuenfterSchritt_ml.png}
         \caption{}
         \label{fig:fuenfterSchrittml}
     \end{subfigure}%
     \hfil
     \makebox[0.3\textwidth]{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}cl@{}}
         (\subref{fig:ersterSchrittml}) & Erster Schritt nach \Gls{perturbation} \\
         (\subref{fig:zweiterSchrittml}) & Zweiter Schritt nach \Gls{perturbation} \\
         (\subref{fig:dritterSchrittml}) & Dreiter Schritt nach \Gls{perturbation} \\
         (\subref{fig:zweiterSchrittml}) & Vierter Schritt nach \Gls{perturbation} \\
         (\subref{fig:fuenfterSchrittml}) & Fünfter Schritt nach \Gls{perturbation}
     \end{tabular}}
    
     \caption{Mittelwerte der \Glsxtrshort{mos}-\Glsxtrshort{ml} [mm] der Assessments. Es wird unterschieden nach Richtung der
        \Gls{perturbation} und Zeitpunkt des Assessments. Untersucht wurden die ersten fünf Schritte nach Auftreten einer
        \Gls{perturbation}}
        \label{fig:fuenfSchritteml}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4-5]
\end{document}
```

---

You can save even more space by putting the subcaptions beside the images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[!b]
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{figures/ErsterSchritt_ml.png}%
     \begin{subfigure}{2em}
         \caption{}\label{fig:ersterSchrittml}
     \end{subfigure}%
     \hfil
     \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{figures/ZweiterSchritt_ml.png}%
     \begin{subfigure}{2em}
         \caption{}\label{fig:zweiterSchrittml}
     \end{subfigure}
     \end{figure}%
  \begin{figure}[tb!]
  \ContinuedFloat
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{figures/DritterSchritt_ml.png}%
     \begin{subfigure}{2em}
         \caption{}\label{fig:dritterSchrittml}
     \end{subfigure}%
     \hfil
     \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{figures/VierterSchritt_ml.png}%
     \begin{subfigure}{2em}
         \caption{}\label{fig:vierterSchrittml}
     \end{subfigure}
     \end{figure}%
  \begin{figure}[t]% if they all fit on ome page, you wouldn't be doing this
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
     \sbox9{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{figures/FuenfterSchritt_ml.png}}% measure height
     \usebox9
     \begin{subfigure}{2em}
         \caption{}\label{fig:fuenfterSchrittml}
     \end{subfigure}%
     \hfil
     \raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\ht9 - 0.5\height + 0.5\depth}{% center align with image
       \makebox[\dimexpr 0.3\textwidth+2em]{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}cl@{}}
         (\subref{fig:ersterSchrittml}) & Erster Schritt nach \Gls{perturbation} \\
         (\subref{fig:zweiterSchrittml}) & Zweiter Schritt nach \Gls{perturbation} \\
         (\subref{fig:dritterSchrittml}) & Dritter Schritt nach \Gls{perturbation} \\
         (\subref{fig:zweiterSchrittml}) & Vierter Schritt nach \Gls{perturbation} \\
         (\subref{fig:fuenfterSchrittml}) & Fünfter Schritt nach \Gls{perturbation}
     \end{tabular}}}
    
     \caption{Mittelwerte der \Glsxtrshort{mos}-\Glsxtrshort{ml} [mm] der Assessments. Es wird unterschieden nach Richtung der
        \Gls{perturbation} und Zeitpunkt des Assessments. Untersucht wurden die ersten fünf Schritte nach Auftreten einer
        \Gls{perturbation}}
        \label{fig:fuenfSchritteml}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```