# revtex + longtblr + turnpage

Tags: tables, landscape, revtex, tabularray, longtblr

I write a paper with `revtex` and would like have a long wide table which spans over multiple pages in landscape mode (as shown on pics below). Is there a way to achieve this?

If I put a `longtblr` table inside the `table` environment, I cannot make `\pagebreak`s, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74866943/12996332).

If I don't put it into the `table` environment, I cannot use the `turnpage`:

*To use the turnpage environment, simply enclose the figure or table environment with the turnpage environment:
<...>
A turnpage float will be typeset on a page by itself. Currently, there is no mechanism for breaking such a float across multiple pages.* (From [revtex manual](https://d22izw7byeupn1.cloudfront.net/files/revtex/auguide4-1.pdf).)

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

The desired output, two-column portrait document with a table spanning over multiple rotated pages:
[image]

- Attempt #1:

```
\documentclass[
aps,
twocolumn,
prx
% ,landscape 
]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-6]
\newpage
\begin{widetext}
\begin{turnpage} % Doesn't work for {longtblr}
\begin{longtblr}{Q[10cm]|Q[10cm]}
    \lipsum[1-3] & \lipsum[1-3] \\
    \lipsum[1-3] & \lipsum[1-3]
\end{longtblr}   
\end{turnpage}
\end{widetext}
\end{document}
```

The code above does not produce the desired outcome because `turnpage` cannot be applied to `longtblr`.

- Attempt #2:

```
\documentclass[
aps,
twocolumn,
prx
]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-6]
\newpage
\begin{widetext}
\begin{turnpage}
\begin{table}
\begin{longtblr}{Q[10cm]|Q[10cm]}
    \lipsum[1-3] & \lipsum[1-3] \\
    \newpage % Doesn't work inside the {table}
    \lipsum[1-3] & \lipsum[1-3]
\end{longtblr}   
\end{table}
\end{turnpage}
\end{widetext}
\end{document}
```

The code above doesn't work because the `\newpage` cannot be used inside `table`.

Comment: Any kind of long table should not be incapsulated in `table` float environment! If for some reason need to be in `table` than you need to split table into two parts similarly as is done (for sub tables) in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/278748/.

Comment: For further help please provide an MWE (with dummy content), which reproduce your problem,

Comment: Please see now.

Comment: Any news? Does my answer help you?

Comment: Thank you. It is not a solution I was hoping to find but it is a solution :D I was expecting some lengthy unparsable monkey patch.

Comment: Yu may consider, that publisher doesn't like that article has long tables? And for purpose limit template that author will not do this? Try to make table such, that will fit on portrait oriented pages, where is not this limitations. I would delete my answer, that some other will help you with "lengthy unparsable monkey patch" ...

Comment: But please keep it for now! I don't have anything better.

Comment: Why? Apparently it has no worth to you. If it would had, than you were awarded it with upvote ...