# Issue with subfigure split across multiple pages

Tags: subfloats, figure-placement

I have 4 subfigures that I want to be presented across two pages, with 2 on each page. (Each set of two subfigs is large enough to take the entire page).
I followed the suggestions here: [Split subfigures over multiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages)
I went through the comments, but there were no solutions there.

However, whatever I try, LaTeX always inserts content between the first set of two subfigures and the last set (i.e. text and tables). Is there a way to force the subfigures to be shown after one another, please?

My code:

```
    \begin{figure}[!b]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.85\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{path}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{fig:label}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{0.85\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{path}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{fig:label2}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}%

  % Add a page break here
%\clearpage

\begin{figure}[ht]\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.85\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{path}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{fig:label3}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{0.85\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{path}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{fig:label4}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption[]{Caption text }
    \label{fig:figlabel}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks :)

Edit:

After the figure, I have a new subsection and then a table definition (this table is showing up in between the subfigs:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
    \begin{longtable}[htp]{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.15\textwidth} >{
                \arraybackslash}m{0.325\textwidth} >{\arraybackslash}m{0.325\textwidth} }
        \caption{caption } \\
        \label{tab:label}
        \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text}\\ \midrule 
        \endfirsthead
        \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text}\\ \midrule
         \endhead
    
        Text & Text & Text\\
        
        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text\\
        
        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text\\ 
        
        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text \\
        
        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text\\
        
        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text\\
        
        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text\\
        
        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text\\
        
        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text\\

        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text\\
        
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
```

It's text heavy.

Comment: If your figures are really large enough to take up an entier page, you should use [p] floats.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem by starting the longtable **before** the first page float was printed.  That is, not enough text was provided to fill the first page.  The first float was already moved to `\@botlist` while the second float was still in `\@deferlist`.  Add `\newpage` before the longtable.

Comment: @JohnKormylo this seemed to fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should suffice to replace `\begin{figure}[ht]` with `\begin{figure}[t!]`.

Incidentally, there's no need to write `\subcaption` inside a `subfigure` environment; `\caption` will do just fine.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] % a paragraph of filler text

\begin{figure}[!b]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.85\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{patha}
        \caption{abcdef}
        \label{fig:labela}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{0.85\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pathb}
        \caption{ghijkl}
        \label{fig:labelb}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \caption{Stuff}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.85\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pathc}
        \caption{mnopqr}
        \label{fig:labelc}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{0.85\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pathd}
        \caption{stuvwx}
        \label{fig:labeld}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \caption{Stuff, continued}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-5] % four more paragraphs of filler text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the same issue, with the next set showing up two pages down the line after the table. Could it be because the table is declared as such?
\begin{longtable}[htp]

Comment: @wiltabone - Sadly (but maybe not surprisingly), my psychic divination skills are utterly worthless. If you want to improve the odds of somebody figuring out how to help you with a complex document setup, do please edit your posting to provide all relevant, but so far missing, information. E.g., have you queued up a `table` float before starting the `figure` floats?

Comment: The command `\begin{longtable}[htp]` contains at least one syntax error and one meaningless element. First, a `longtable` environment takes a mandatory argument, which you don't appear to provide: The list of column types. E.g., `\begin{longtable}{|lcccc|}`, for a five-column table bounded on both sides by vertical rules. Second, the positioning specifier `[htp]` does nothing at all here, since `longtable` environments aren't floats (in the LaTeX-specific sense of the term).

Comment: There is no table queued before the figure. Following that is a block of text and the start of a new subsection. Then the long table argument is created:
**{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
 \begin{longtable}[htp]{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth} | >{
    \arraybackslash}m{0.4\textwidth} >{\arraybackslash}m{0.4\textwidth} }**

Comment: I have amended my question above with the declaration in full.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full MWE I used to replicate the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{duckuments}% don't ask
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!b]
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:label}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:label2}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}%

\begin{figure}[t!]\ContinuedFloat
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:label3}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:label4}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption[]{Caption text }
    \label{fig:figlabel}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

%\newpage
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
    \begin{longtable}[htp]{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.15\textwidth} >{
                \arraybackslash}m{0.325\textwidth} >{\arraybackslash}m{0.325\textwidth} }
        \caption{caption } \\
        \label{tab:label}
        \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text}\\ \midrule 
        \endfirsthead
        \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text}\\ \midrule
         \endhead
    
        Text & Text & Text\\
        
        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text\\
        
        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text\\ 
        
        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text \\
        
        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text\\
        
        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text\\
        
        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text\\
        
        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text\\
        
        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text\\

        \midrule
        
        Text & Text & Text\\
        
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```