What to do when we use subfig and the images occupy more than one page?
I'm writing my thesis and I have a group of images, but the image group takes up more than one page. How do I ensure that the subfig continues on the next page with the correct figure count?
\begin{subfig}
     \centering
     \subfloat[First.]{...}
     \quad
     \subfloat[Second figure.]{...}
     \quad
     \subfloat[Third.]{\label{3figs-c}...}
     \caption{Three sub-floats.}
     \label{3figs}
\end{subfig}


Welcome to TeX.SE! See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages/278748#278748 can help you.
