Referencing subfigures with custom captions that span across multiple pages
I have two large subfigures that take up a page each (i.e., I can't stack both vertically or display them side-by-side on the same page).
I'm also using custom captions with \caption*{} because I want to label each as "Fig 1A" and "Fig 1B". However, I can't seem to reference any of the subfigures (or the entire figure) in the text.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
Referencing first subfigure \ref{fig:1a}, second one \ref{fig:1b}, and the entire figure \ref{fig:1}.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.95]{fig1a.png}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption*{\textbf{Fig. 1A.} This is my figure 1A.}
    \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \ContinuedFloat
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{fig1b.png}
        \label{fig:1b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption*{\textbf{Fig. 1B.} Here's another figure.}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


As I understood it, you wanted more than just sub-figures, you wanted sub-figures with bold labels and capital letters. You also wanted 'Fig.' instead of 'Figure' and to have a subcaption without a main caption in at least the first picture. So I wrote an answer which did all that, by which time you'd accepted an answer which didn't and somebody had closed the question as a duplicate of a question about something which asked for none of that.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724797/ but I will have to delete it because it doesn't answer the alleged duplicate.

You would rather split a figure over two pages than simply fill in the gap with text by using [ht] instead of [H]?

Considering @cfr comments, the following MWE works as you expected:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
Referencing first subfigure \ref{fig:1a}, second one \ref{fig:1b}, and the entire figure \ref{fig:1}.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Here's subfigure figure A.}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{This is my figure 1}
    \end{figure}
    
\begin{figure}[H]
    \ContinuedFloat
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Here's subfigure B.}
    \label{fig:1b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{This is my figure 1}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Some remarks:

subfigure package is obsolete
Your question seems to be duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/278748.


@CarLaTeX, by error. One is sufficient. Corrected now. Thank you very much!

You're welcome! Ciao!
